# How do I throw an item in The Cave?

Tags: android, the-cave

I read in the walkthrough, that you have to throw the hotdog into the pit on the spikes by the monster, but I don't know how to throw it. I can only lay it down the the feet of my character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stand next to the pit with the character that has the hot dog and then just tap on the spikes